# Calculating Limits Using Limit Laws: How Can I Show/Prove This?

Tags: calculus

How can I show/prove that the limit of a sum may exist even though the limits of each of the operands does not exist?

Comment: Consider $x_n=(-1)^n$, $y_n=(-1)^{n+1}$.

Comment: $\displaystyle{\large \lim_{x \to 0}\left[{1 \over x} + \left(-\,{1 \over x}\right)\right] = 0}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At its crudest, use a badly behaved $f(x)$, and let $g(x)=-f(x)$. The sum $f(x)+g(x)$ is always $0$, very nicely behaved!

Comment: As simple and direct as that. +1